# How do I update the template as a scope variable is updated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

What I want is that when the value of **orderHistory.type** (**a scope variable whose initial value is 'list'**) is changed to 'show', the **showOrder.html** template is rendered. The function updating orderHistory.type is called through a clicking on a link in o**rderHistoryList.html.** The model is getting updated, the template doesn't change though. Thanks Already.

```
<div data-ng-controller="SettingsController">
    <div ng-if="orderHistory.type=='list'" data-ng-include="'orderHistoryList.html'"></div>
    <div ng-if="orderHistory.type=='show'"data-ng-include="'showOrder.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Is that even possible this way?

Comment: Got it, I made a mistake in setting the attribute ng-controller in orderHistoryList.html as well, that made different instances of the SettingsController on both the pages. So when the model was updated in one of the instances, it didnt show any changes on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I made a mistake in setting the attribute ng-controller in orderHistoryList.html as well, that made different instances of the SettingsController on both the pages. So when the model was updated in one of the instances, it didnt show any changes on the main page.